# Splitting a bit array into smaller arrays in Verilog

Tags: verilog

This is probably easy, but sadly I can't really find the answer.
Let's say I have...

```
input [31:0] controls;
```

How would I declare a bit array I can return that equals a segment of those bits, such as 6-0 or 31-25?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question (it's a little vague to me), but are you just looking for this?

```
wire [6:0] controls_part;
assign controls_part = controls[31:25];
```

Or can you elaborate a little more?